# django_settings_module is undefined on GAE server

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

So, I know you guys have been asked this question a million times, believe me I think I have read them all. I am getting the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined error when trying to convert the Django polls app (the one made in the django tutorial) to run on the google app engine using the google cloud SQL.

Here is the actual stack trace given to me by the google app engine logs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 223, in Handle 
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 219, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 39, in load_middleware
    for middleware_path in settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES:
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/utils/functional.py", line 184, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/third_party/django-1.4/django/conf/__init__.py", line 40, in _setup
    raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
  ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
```

I was getting the same error when trying to run it on dev_appserver.py provided with the google app engine but managed to remedy that by adding

```
  env_variables:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'DjangoTut.settings'
```

to the app.yaml file.

my project directory looks like this:

- DjangoTut

  - DjangoTut

    - **init**.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    - wsgi.py
  - polls

    - **init**.py
    - admin.py
    - models.py
    - tests.py
    - urls.py
    - views.py
  - app.yaml
  - manage.py

and my app.yaml file looks like this

```
   application: hochotime
   version: 10
   runtime: python27
   api_version: 1
   threadsafe: true


   libraries:
   - name: django
     version: "1.4"

   builtins:
   - django_wsgi: on

   env_variables:
     DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'settings'
```

every other file is identical to those suggested here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/

I have tried adding

```
    import os
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'DjangoTut.settings'
```

to the start of just about every single python file but to no avail. I have tried moving the settings file into the project directory rather than the app directory and changing all the `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']` to point to just 'settings'. I have also tried configuring the settings directly as shown here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#using-settings-without-setting-django-settings-module but still, I get the same error whenever I try to run it on the google servers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using [Django-nonrel](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel)?  If not, take a look at this [appengine ariticle](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/django).

I would try moving settings.py out to the same directory as app.yaml.  The remove the env_variables from app.yaml, you shouldn't need those for it to work.  However you will need handlers defined if you don't already (not sure if you listed your whole app.yaml or not):

```
  handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: main.py
```

The environment setting should be in the wsgi handler you setup (main.py in this example) *as shown in the google article above.*

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
```

Hope this gets you going down the right path.

Comment: I am not using Django-nonrel because, as I hear it, this way of running django on top of the GAE has been deprecated in favour of this https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django. That is the entirety of my app.yaml file however after trying those additions and changing the yaml file to make sure it is no loner threadsafe (apparently this throws an error) and I still get an error both when running it locally and uploading it to the google servers.